# How to pass condition to function?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I want to reduce repeated code. Below is a snippet of code

```
void f1(string arg)
{
        std::map <string,string> topicAndClientIdMap;
        for(auto topicAndClientId : topicAndClientIdMap)
        {
            if(topicAndClientId.second == arg1)
            {
             //inset in other map
            }
         }
}

void f2(string arg)
{
        std::map <string,string> topicAndClientIdMap;
        for(auto topicAndClientId : topicAndClientIdMap)
         {
           if(topicAndClientId.first.contains(arg1))
           {
               //insert in other map
           }
        }

}
```

I want to create a common function for `f1` and `f2` where I can pass condition as well.

Comment: You are looking for [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), likely embedded in a [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each).

Comment: You are really looking for [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), or a variant here, from the algorithm library.

Comment: `topicAndClientIdMap` is a local variable in both functions. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Please make a [mre] so it's clear what it is you're trying to refactor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a `std::function`, e.g.

```
void f(const std::function<bool(string, string)>& doInclude)
{
    for (const auto& [key, value] : topicAndClientIdMap)
        if (doInclude(key, value))
            ; // do stuff...
}
```

which could be called as

```
f([&arg](const auto&, const auto& value) { return value == arg; });

f([&arg](const auto& key, const auto&) { return key.contains(arg); });
```

Here, the `std::function` argument is initialized with a lambda expression that encapsulates the filtering check in your snippets for `f1` and `f2` (but note that I don't know what `string` is - if it's `std::string`, that doesn't have a `contains` member function, so the above won't compile, as well as the original snippet your posted).

Comment: Yes I am using qt's QString which is having contains function For the simplicity of spinet I used std:: string. Thanks for quick solution

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates).

```cpp
// only a demo snippet

using std::string;

std::map<string, string> topicAndClientIdMap;
// Initiate topicAndClientIdMap with some data

template <typename FUNC>
void TmplF(std::string& arg, FUNC f) {
    for (auto& topicAndClientId : topicAndClientIdMap) {
        f(topicAndClientId)
    }
    // other operations...
}

int main() {
    std::string arg = "str";
    TmplF(arg, [&arg](std::pair<string, string>& p) {
        if (p.second == arg) {
            // do whatever you want...
        }
    });
    TmplF(arg, [&arg](std::pair<string, string>& p) {
        if (p.first.contains(arg)) {
            // do whatever you want...
        }
    });
}
```